# How to calculate current in a complex circuit?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, kirchhoffs-laws, homework

[image]

Regarding a) How do I calculate the current for I<sub>1</sub>?

Regarding b) How do I calculate I<sub>A</sub>?

I have calculated I<sub>3</sub> and I<sub>4</sub> by using I = V/R and got the following:

I<sub>3</sub> = 5 V/10000 Ω and
I<sub>4</sub> = 5 V/100000 Ω

Comment: Welcome! EE pro tip: use engineering notation. 100000 ohm = 100 kohm. Regarding your assignment, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck? How can you simplify the circuit?

Comment: You're asking for help with what looks like school work.  But you've don't nothing but state the problem.  You've not shown that you have done any work or research of your own.  This is not a "homework" forum.  That being said, why don't you try simplifying this "complex" circuit by combining some of these resistors using the rules for series and parallel combination of resistance values?

Comment: You use mesh or loop analyis with Kirchoff's Voltage Law or Kirchoff's Current Law. It sounds like you have not learned these methods yet.

Comment: it is not a complex circuit per se ... you calculated I3 and I4 ... what is preventing you from. calculating I1? ... do I3 and I4 interact? ... what happens to I3 if you remove R4?

Answer (score 1):

See that R1 and R2 are in series, with nothing else connected between them. That means you can easily convert them to a single resistance, which I am sure you know how to do.

Once you have all three branch currents, then you can apply Kirchhoff's current law (KCL) at the junction (top of voltage source \$V_A\$) where \$I_A\$ splits into \$I_1\$, \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$. That will enable you to find \$I_A\$, since all the others are now known.

A word of warning; pay attention to the signs of values. When you apply KCL, you might be surprised at the value you get for \$I_A\$.